# Button Disappears on Load

Tags: jquery

Can someone please tell me why my "toggle" button is disappearing after the page is loaded? It closes/opens my sliding panel when clicked. It is visible first for a second then disappears when the page loads. [Here is the JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/355uzcft/21/).

```js
$('.toggle').toggle(function() {
  $('#one').animate({
    width: 0
  });
  $('#two').animate({
    left: 0
  });
}, function() {
  $('#one').animate({
    width: 200
  });
  $('#two').animate({
    left: 200
  });
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#one,
#two {
  position: absolute;
}

#one {
  top: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: lime;
}

#two {
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#toggle {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='one'></div>
<div id='two'>

  <p>
    test
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="" class='toggle'>Toggle</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: because you are toggling the button thats why

Comment: Check this link: [Jquery Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/);    API: .toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] ) Description: Display or hide the matched elements.

Comment: Sorry I am still learning jQuery, so I would need to .click the button then toggle the function.

Comment: see the answer i posted , hope that you are trying to toggle the left panel when clicking on the toggle button see if that helps you out ,

Comment: Post a [mcve] *in your question* please

Comment: @j08691 the fiddle link is added thou

Comment: I can see that. However, if jsFiddle ever goes away, is down, or is blocked by something like a corporate firewall, then your question loses all value, which is why it's a rule here to post a [mcve] in your question and not only on a third-party site.

Comment: @j08691 So for future reference I don't need a Fiddle anymore just post a complete example.

Comment: Yes. There's even a built-in snippet function that allows you to embed a runnable example in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not toggling the div instead the button you should bind `click` on the `.toggle` button and then check the `width` of the `#one` to hide or show the left panel i hope that is what you are trying to acheive

```js
$('.toggle').on('click', function() {

  if ($('#one').width()) {
    $('#one').animate({
      width: 0,
    });
    $('#two').animate({
      left: 0,
    });
  } else {
    $('#one').animate({
      width: 200,
    });
    $('#two').animate({
      left: 200
    });
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#one,
#two {
  position: absolute;
}

#one {
  top: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: lime;
}

#two {
  top: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: pink;
}

#toggle {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='one'></div>
<div id='two'>

  <p>
    test
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#>" class='toggle'>Toggle</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: another thing you should use `$('.toggle').on('click',function() {` rather than `$('.toggle').click(function() {` i just updated the code @webmonkey237

Answer (score 0):

Because you call toggle it self.

Try to use:

```
$('.toggle').hover
```

Instead of:

```
$('.toggle').toggle
```

And you will see the difference.

Other problem is the toogle button are inside the divs. Must put outside od divs.

Take a look in docs:
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I don't think this really addresses the OP's problem. Why use hover? Why can't you place a button inside a DIV and attach a toggle trigger to it?

Comment: Use hover just to test.